# Animate background images within one data attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to create a nice animation between these background images urls, which are live in one data attribute (first image loads immediately, after 5 second the next images, after the next etc. After last one it starts from the beginning).

```
<div data-images="/media/jtjglhbb/main-bg-01.jpg,/media/u2bitolk/main-bg-02.jpg,/media/iasbuo5n/main-bg-04.jpg,/media/f00jm2va/main-bg-03.jpg,"></div>

var $dataImages = $('[data-images]');
var imagesList = $dataImages.data('images').split(',');

$.each(imagesList, function (index, value) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $dataImages.stop().animate({ opacity: 0 }, 1000, function () {
            $(this).css({ 'background-image': 'url(' + imagesList[index] + ')' })
                .animate({ opacity: 1 }, { duration: 1000 });
        });
    }, 5000);
});
```

But it doesn't set up the first image, it only starts after 5 second and it runs altogether not one by one with 5 sec delay.

Obviously the logic is wrong, some help would be great.

Comment: Of course it all runs together - `setTimeout` is not a “sleep” or anything. You are looping over x array elements, and add something to do five seconds _from now_ for all of them.

Comment: A trivial way is to use `5000 * (index + 1)` as the delay

Comment: If you use (5000 * (index + 1)), the first image will set after 5 seconds, use (5000 * index) instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like below. It should work.

1. image count will required to get mode value to start from beginning again.
2. `index` will hold index of image to show in background
3. `changeImage` function will be called recursively from inside so it will continuously update background.
4. use `index = (index + 1) % imageCount;` so index will start from 0 again from last index.

```js
var $dataImages = $('[data-images]');
var imagesList = $dataImages.data('images').split(',');
// image count will required to get mode value to start from beginning again.
var imageCount = imagesList.length - 1;
// index of image to show in background
var index = 0;

// function will be called recursively from inside so it will continuously update background.
function changeImage() {

  $dataImages.stop().animate({
    opacity: 0
  }, 1000, function() {
    $(this).css({
        'background-image': 'url(' + imagesList[index] + ')'
      })
      .animate({
        opacity: 1
      }, {
        duration: 1000
      });
  });

  // update index to next image url
  index = (index + 1) % imageCount;

  // declare timeout to call function after required time
  setTimeout(changeImage, 5000);
}

changeImage();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div style="height: 150px;" data-images="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_nature_wide.jpg,https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_snow_wide.jpg,https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_lights_wide.jpg,https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_mountains_wide.jpg"></div>
```